# SQL Server inserts within a trigger to a linked MySQL server not working

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I'm trying to test inserts to a linked MySQL server using triggers, but am having a few problems.

System-
Windows 2003 Server running
 - SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition
 - MySQL 5.5.15.0 Server
 - MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver

I followed the instructions in this post - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx to link the MySQL server to SQL server

I can SELECT and INSERT rows in the linked server using the query window in SSMS.

The problem arises when I try to do an INSERT to the linked server in a trigger
Trigger

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[update_trig] on [dbo.test]
for insert
as
SET XACT_ABORT ON
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'select data from roh.test') values ('testing trigger')
```

When a row is inserted into the SQL server the following error occurs

Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure update_trig, Line 7
The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

After doing a bit of googling someone suggested adding a COMMIT statement to the trigger after SET XACT_ABORT ON, so the last part of the trigger looks like

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
COMMIT
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'select data from roh.test') values ('testing trigger')
```

This does do the insert in the linked MySQL server but gives the error -

Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Someone also suggested doing the insert in a stored procedure and calling this from the trigger, but this gives the same errors.
Am I missing something, or is this not possible? Any suggestions would be appreciated.